# phpMyAdmin having problems on nginx and php-fpm on RHEL 6

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

We have a web server setup with nginx and php-fpm on [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 6 (RHEL). This machine already has WordPress installed, and it runs great. We have WordPress set up to go to *wptest.domain.local*. We then created a new site in sites-enabled called *servername.domain.local*, where we wanted to host various tools.

PHP works fine throughout, and we don't have any issues with WordPress. But when trying to reach phpMyAdmin, we get this error:

`2012/09/14 16:22:13 [error] 10065#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.15, server: servername, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/setup/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "servername"`

And here is our site's configuration:

```
    server_name servername severname.domain.local;
    access_log /srv/www/severname/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/severname/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/severname/public_html;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/severname/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

PHPmyadmin is installed at `/srv/www/servername/public_html/phpmyadmin/`.

Yesterday I noticed it said there were some SEGFAULT errors too from phpMyAdmin.

If I put a *phpinfo* file in this directory, it works fine. The *phpinfo* included in phpMyAdmin (which has an include, etc.) doesn't work.

The browser displays a ***502 Bad Gateway***.

Also, usually after a php-fpm restart, I will see a red box saying ***phpmyadmin -error***, then ***cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.*** I tried enabling PHP logging, but I got nothing.

I do get this in my error log for the site if I go to *phpmyadmin/setup*:

```
2012/09/18 08:12:43 [error] 16722#0: *22 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_5d9vhk4jv1f07v2jsltlnp8tdnp7s167, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.1.11, server: servername, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/setup/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "servername"
```

Comment: PHP threw an error. Make sure you're logging them somewhere (see `/etc/php.ini`), and then go see what it is.

Comment: I won't be able to get back on the machine until Monday but will turn on PHP logging then. Would that be more helpful than the php-fpm logs? I couldn't get anything out of them.

Comment: I enabled logging, and restarted nginx, but it never actually wrote anything to the log file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the latest error you posted, it appears that PHP is trying to write session data to disk in a directory that's not actually writable, namely `/var/lib/php/session`.

Check the ownership and permissions on this directory:

```
ls -ld /var/lib/php/session
```

Compare these to the user and group ID under which php-fpm is running. These will be found in the `user =` and `group =` declarations in PHP-FPM's pool configuration in `/etc/php-fpm.conf` or files in the `/etc/php-fpm.d/` directory.

Comment: This was actually it (fixed it before seeing this posted). A sys admin installed Apache on here, which screwed up our nginx setup. When I fixed the nginx permissions recently, it actually broke this, because it was expecting an apache user.